# Search Engine in Java?

Tags: java, search-engine

1. I am trying to create a search engine just to learn and get more experience in Java.

   My intention is to store about 100 files on a server, a mixture of html, xml, doc, txt, and for each file to have meta data.

   SO when i search for a keyword, it should display a file with its meta description like Google.

   My question is, apart from html, can you add meta data to any other file formats, so that the meta description is shown.
2. Would you be able to point me towards a Java search engine, that can search within file formats (txt,html) and display the result.

   I am working on my own code for this, but would like to have a look at other peoples code for some help?

Answer (score 27):

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) is the canonical Java search engine.

For adding documents from a variety of sources, take a look at [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) and for a full-blown system with service/web interfaces, [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Lucene allows arbitrary metadata to be associated with its documents. Tika will automatically cull metadata from a variety of formats.

Answer (score 5):

> 1)My question is apart from html can you add meta data to any other file formats, so that the meta description is shown.

In general you would use a database and store the metadata along with the document there.
You'd then do a keyword search using a database query (possibly using SQL like or ilike).

The files might either be stored on the harddrive with just paths in the DB or put into the database as either CLOB or BLOB, depending on whether you have text or binary documents.

> 2) Would you be able to point be towards a Java search engine, that can search within file formats (txt,html) and displays the result.

Try [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

Look at [apache nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/)

```
Apache Nutch is an open source web-search software project.
```

Nutch builds on top of lucene/solr for indexing, tika for parsing documents, and adds its own web crawler.

Answer (score 3):

The really good is [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html). There are lot of plugins (that would allow for example you read from .doc), support multiple languages and lot of algorithms (like  Levenshtein distance)

Answer (score 3):

- Google ignores completely meta descriptions nowadays, because it has been either abused, or not filled with significant values
- [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) and/or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) might do what you want, take a look.
- 100 files is a very small amount, you won't have any problem to manage this amount of data in any way you like, if it's for exercise.

Answer (score 3):

... [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) and [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) come to mind as far other people's code is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use several libraries. First of all, as many people mentioned before you can use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) to do the actual searching. However, Lucene only handles plain text, so you need to extract this from the files you index.
For this, you could use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/).

To get started, you should probably buy the book [Lucene in Action 2nd edition](http://www.manning.com/hatcher3/). Most of the examples in there are still up to date. If you want to be a cheapskate you could also just look at the provided source code on that page.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to extract **metadata**.

> Apache Tika The Apache Tika toolkit is an ASFv2 licensed open source
>   tool for extracting information from digital documents. Tika allows
>   search engines, content management systems and other applications that
>   work with various kinds of digital documents to easily detect and
>   extract metadata and content from all major file formats.